# Convert a set of unique numbers to another set of unique numbers within range (0 to 25)

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers, scaling, sampling

Lets say I have a set of unique numbers [5, 123, 49176, 30982, 542] now I want to convert the numbers and get another set of unique numbers (integers) which will be in range of 0 to 25

Can any one suggest any algorithm that can help me solve this problem ?

Comment: What are the constraints? From your question 0,1,2,3... Is a valid answer but probably not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You are going to normalize them?

```
raw =  [5, 123, 49176, 30982, 542] 

normalization = [(i-min(raw))/(max(raw)-min(raw))*25 for i in raw]
print(normalization)
```

It will give you: (all elements are guaranteed to be unique)

```
[0.0, 0.059994712330438675, 25.0, 15.749628846271177, 0.2730267840800472]
```

---

If the elements of result are limited to be integer:

```
import random
raw =  [5, 1, 23, 49176, 30982, 542] 

if len(raw) > 26: #there's no way to get more than 26 unique elements from 0~25 integers 
    print("mission impossible")
else:
    print(random.sample(range(26), len(raw)))
```

It will give you (for example):

```
[23, 4, 13, 10, 18, 24]
```

---

Those are two compromising way for you. But according to you comment, you actually need a **injective function whose domain are all integers and codomain are integers in [0,25]**. Unfortunately, it's a mission impossible.

Comment: Even with a set larger than 25?

Comment: @Chris: assuming the OP is not asking for integers - this is the solution, and there is no limitation on the set size, note that there are infinite (Alef, non-enumerable infinity) number of *real numbers* in the range `[0,25]` (In practive there is finite number of these because of floating point arithmetics issues, and the fact that we cannot represent all real numbers with our machines)

Comment: @amit You left me a comment! My idol left me a comment!

Comment: @Skyler: lol. If I knew it is so important to you, I would have done it a long time ago. Anyway, I +1ed your answer since, as I said, it is the way to do it if not assuming integers (which my answer assumed). Since the question is not clear regarding this issue, IMHO - both are valid.

Comment: Yes, the input numbers will always be integers and the result should be integer only. Now, Does this algorithm guarantee that the given number x will always result in number y ?

Comment: @sudhir It guaranteed that all elements are unique, but **not** that a given x always maps to a certain y. It's easy to prove that there's **no** function could guarantee it with a range of 0~25 integers .

Comment: @sudhir Do the raw set and the result set have to be in the same size?

Comment: @Skyler yeah, input and output should be of same size, infact I need to map input numbers to their corresponding output values

Comment: @sudhir, so you actually need an **injective function whose domain are all integers and codomain are integers in [0,25]**. Unfortunately, it's a mission impossible.

Answer (score 2):

(Assuming integers)

You can **sort the elements, and give each element its index** (in the sorted list). Assuming you have less then (or exactly) 26 numbers, you will get the desired range. You can also avoid sorting if you can allow not deterministic result for the same set by just setting the numbers as the current order (iteration order, for example) of the set.

Note that if you want some general case hashing, it cannot be done - if your *range* is greater then 26 - you will have duplicates. This is coming directly from [Pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), where the range is the pigeons, and the range [0,25] is the Pigeonholes.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, the range `[0,25]` contains 26 pigeonholes but I agree with the rest of what you write.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: Yes, of course. I thought of [0,25) while writing it for some reason (and wrote [0,25], silly me). I'm fixing this issue. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use each number as a seed for a random function, and then go through and make sure you don't have any duplicates.
This will also break down if you have a set larger than 25, like Amit said.